# How is this determinant of (A+B) proved?

Tags: linear-algebra

For a positive integer $n$, let $A$ and $B$ be $n$ by $n$ real matrices such that
$xA + yB = I$ ($x, y$ are real numbers(not zero)), and $AB = 0_n$

so, how can i prove this equation.

$$\det(A+B) = {1\over x^{\operatorname{rank}(A)}y^{\operatorname{rank}(B)}}$$

Comment: How about supposing $A+B=I$, $AB=0$ and proving $\det(xA+yB)=x^{r(A)}y^{r(B)}$ instead?

Comment: i don't know how to get r(A), r(B)... help me!!

Comment: What do you mean by "x,y are real vectors"? They seem to be scalars

Comment: Oh, that's my mistake. x,y are real scalars

Answer (score 0):

For warmup, suppose $A$ (and hence also $B$) is diagonal.  Then the diagonal entries of $A$ and $B$ fall out nicely, and the result follows directly.

Not all matrices are diagonal, however, but you can always reduce to the case where $A$ (and hence $B$ as well) is upper triangular, and then pretty much all of the diagonal case argument still works.